# Twittersearch module is not getting imported to api file

Tags: python

I am trying to make twitter search api everything was working fine but suddenly twittersearch() module is not getting imported. I am using python 3.4.2 with windows 8.1 64-bit. I have tried easy_install twittersearch it successfully installs packages and everything is fine but when I run this code

```
from TwitterSearch import *
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', server='localhost', database='capstone',trusted_connection='yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select word from dbo.search where sl in (select max(sl) from  dbo.search)")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
print (row)
print("This is positive data ")
term = row[0]
try:
tso=TwitterSearchOrder()
tso.set_keywords([term])
tso.set_language('en')
```

When i execute this it shows errors like below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\search_test.py", line 18, in <module>
tso=TwitterSearchOrder()
NameError: name 'TwitterSearchOrder' is not defined
```

But it is actually there I don't know why it is not recognizing the module. till 2 days back it was running successfully with IDLE but not in commandprompt and I have reinstalled the python and added all tools, now it is showing this error in both IDLE and command prompt
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that TwitterSearch is in your lib\site-packages path. If it is you must've installed it right. If not, a simple `python -m pip install TwitterSearch` from command prompt will do.

However, there seems to be an issue([bug](https://github.com/ckoepp/TwitterSearch/issues/27)) with TwitterSearch wrt its functions. You might consider using an alternate API in the meantime. I would suggest using [Tweepy](http://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v3.5.0/)